# Unable to load cloudflare cdn?

Tags: jquery, url, networking, server, cloudflare

Hey Guys I am using cloudflare cdn for jquery cookies and sometime its what happening is that doesn't get load which makes me little puzzled.

As I have also tested that particular url on browser where also server not responding message is showing.

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js”.
```

This is what I am getting in console.

Hope you guys understand...

Comment: use a different cdn, host jquery on your server

Comment: @madalinivascu I also want to know why this problem persisting only on my end...